# How to make sure response in Store belongs to latest Request at React/Flux

Tags: reactjs, request, response, store, flux

I have an input field that I check for validation with `onChange`. On the change event, I fire an action, say: `MyActions.checkUsername()` so that I'll concurrently see if the username is already taken.

The problem is when I check the store to see the response for validation, I get the response value of the previous request. Because it is async.

So what is the ideal way of resolving this problem in React with Flux?

Answer (score 1):

One technique that could help alleviate the problem could be to use the [`debounce`](https://lodash.com/docs#debounce) method of lodash so that you don't spam the checking.

In the *rough* example below I use the debounce of lodash so that the async check will only fire after 500ms of quiet (i.e. after the user stops typing for 500ms).

For example:

```
import { debounce } from 'lodash';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.checkUser = debounce(this.checkUser.bind(this), 500 /*ms*/);
  }

  checkUser(value) {
    // fire async check
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <input onChange={this.checkUser} />
      </form>
    );     
  }
}
```

This may not alleviate the problem completely, but try it out. You could try extending the debounce period too before going for a more complicated solution.

---

If you don't want to add lodash as a dependency, then you could write your own debounce.  Here is an example:

https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

Comment: Thanks. I already tried debounce on check function previously, but for some reason it does not work. Like you said, it's not an ultimate way to resolve anyway, and it'd be nice to know the right way... I can always update the state and validate according to the state, but reluctant to do that...

Comment: How are you firing the async requests?  Are they promise based calls within a `redux-thunk` action creator?

Comment: Not sure indeed, but I can check. Someone else did the flux part. And it's not redux - that I know.